# How can I hook up to a parent's event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an aspx file, and rendered within it is an ascx control.

The aspx file has a button, that, when clicked, fires an event.

I've got a button in the ascx control that I'd like to hook up to that same event...but I'm not clear on how to do it.  I'm obviously missing something fairly elementary.

I was thinking it would be something like this:

```
myButton.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

...

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    <some way to get ahold of the parent aspx>.btn_Click(sender, e)
}
```

But, I've had no luck thus far, which makes me wonder if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Ideas?

Comment: Why not encapsulate the logic in a separate class and call it in both cases ?

Comment: Because it's not really so much complex logic so much as taking all of the values on the parent page, and saving them.  So encapsulating the logic elsewhere would mean sending over a ton of values, to then run not too much code.

Comment: Do you have an access to the parent page's button?

Comment: @Beska: why your control is aware of saving data of the parent page? I believe control should be responsible for its data persistance

Comment: @sll: No, part of my question is how to get ahold of the parent  page's button (or even just the parent aspx).  If I could get that, I could presumably hook up to the same event fairly easily.  I suspect I'm making my question seem more complex than it really is.

Comment: @Beska : The problem is to access parent Page? You simply can do it by accessing Page property within a UserControl and if you need casting it to a specific type, this is what you are looking for? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx

Comment: @sll As for why the control is saving the data of the parent page, it's a design requirement.  On the click, everything that has been modified on the page must be saved, whether in the control, parent control, whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an event handler in the user control, like this:

ASCX markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="UserControlButton" runat="server" OnClick="UserControlButton_Click" />
```

ASCX code-behind:

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClick;

protected void UserControlButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ButtonClick != null)
        ButtonClick(sender, e);
}
```

In the page:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<uc:MyUserControl ID="UserControl1" runat="server" OnButtonClick="Button1_Click" />
```

In the code behind of the page:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if you need to differentiate one button from the other
    if (sender.Equals(Button1))
    {
        //page button logic
    }
    else
    {
        //user control button logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you was right in comment regarding that I've missed a point of the question, thanks

Comment: This nailed it.  I think I'm missing a key element still though, in that I'm not sure exactly how it worked.  The OnButtonClick attribute of the user control is automagically hooked up via the name to the ButtonClick EventHandler?  Is that right?  Zow.  I've got a gaping hole in my knowledge here.  Definitely time to go back and fill in the gaps.

Comment: The event handler in the usercontrol is fired when the button in the usercontrol is clicked. That event handler also exposes an event from the usercontrol to the page, which can be handled by the click event of the button on the page. I know that sounds confusing, but does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In your UserControl add:

```
public Action<object,EventArgs> onMyButtonClick { get; set; }

...

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    btn.Click += (s,ea) => { onMyButtonClick(sender, e); };
}
```

In your .aspx page add:

```
protected Action<object,EventArgs> myClickAction = (s, a) => { /* your handling code goes here */ };

...

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    myUserControlName.onMyButtonClick = myClickAction;
    btn.Click += (s,ea) => { myClickAction(s,ea); };
}
```

Something like this should work. (**NOTE: this code is not tested, may need tweaking**)

Comment: I would use an `EventHandler` instead of the Action delegate. Yes they're equivalent but the EventHandler has been a set standard for years now and it only complicates the code to use an Action instead.

Comment: @PirateKitten I disagree, using an Action can make the code more concise, i updated the code to be a little more concise. It's also a more Functional style of programming and more readable in my opinion. Also notice the accepted answer, you have to go to 4 files to make changes to make this work. With my solution, just 2 code behinds. You can see at a glance what is happening.

Comment: You don't *have* to affect 4 files, you can just as easily hook up to the handlers in the Page_Load of the CS as you have done with the Actions, and many people do.

Comment: @PirateKitten sure, but that is not the demonstrated solution. In any case, there are many ways to accomplish the same thing, i feel my solution is more flexible as well. But this is not worth arguing about, as long as readers see various solutions to the same problem, they can select the one that they feel most comfortable with and the one that is the most appropriate to their situation.